# Python - Changing Class Variable Value in Function

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I'm building a python class to encapsulate a drop-down list and its buttons in one convenient widget and I ran across a problem.

```
class DropDownMenu(DropDown):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(DropDownMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.The_Menu = DropDown()
    self.The_Btns = []
    self.Num_Btns = 0

def Set_Num_Btns(self):
    self.Num_Btns = len(self.The_Btns)

def Create_Menu(self, Btn_Names):

    # Populate List Size Property
    if (self.Num_Btns == 0):
        self.Set_Num_Btns()

    # Add Buttons to the Drop-Down
    for i in range(0, self.Num_Btns):
        self.The_Btns.append(Button(text = Btn_Names[i], size_hint_y = None, height = 20))
        self.The_Menu.add_widget(self.The_Btns[i])
```

It compiles fine and when I try to create a drop-down menu, I get what I want:

```
self.File_Menu = DropDownMenu()
self.File_Menu.Create_Menu(self.File_Menu_Names)
self.add_widget(self.File_Menu)
```

But, if I try to bind any of the buttons to anything, like so:

```
self.File_Menu.The_Btns[0].bind(on_release = self.Insert_File_Menu.open)
```

The compiler throws an exception saying the list was out-of-bounds. On further inspection, I realized that even though I'm calling the Create_Menu function, the value of The_Btns is not being changed from an empty list. So, my question is: how do I fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, python doesn't "compile" in the sense that you refer to, and doesn't have a compiler.  Also, have a look at [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

To answer your question, You are iterating over a range, 0 to `Num_Btns`.  However, in `Set_Num_Btns`, you set the variable to `len(self.The_Btns)`, which is an empty list, i.e. you are iterating over `range(0, 0)`.  I suspect you mean to do soemthing like this:

```
for name in Btn_Names:
    self.The_Btns.append(Button(text=name, ...))
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new to python so some of the conventions haven't sunk in yet. This should fix the problem I'm having